# Template class specialization to handle its own type

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I've been playing around with templates to get a feel for them and i wanted to do a class  specialization on its own type. I searched the internet for a while but i found no mention of this.

For example if i have a `class Array`:

```
template<class T>
class Array{
 ...
 void print();
}
```

Is it possible to specialize method `print()` when `T=Array<unspecified type>`?

```
template<class T>
void Array<Array<T>>::print(){
    //do something diffrent for array of array
    //this code wont work
}
```

I managed to do this

```
template<>
void Array<Array<int>>::print(){
    //print in matrix format
    //this code works
}
```

I don't see this feature being extremely useful, but i was nonetheless curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can perform a specialization only for the whole class. Once I needed something like that (actually, I just needed two `typedef`s to be different), so I created an auxiliary class which contained only the members that had to be specialized, and made the principal class inherit from it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a feature called partial specialization where you could apply something like this. However, I don't believe that you can partially specialize member functions without partially specializing the whole class.